# Set speed based on agents close to transporter

Tags: loops, anylogic

In my model, I want my agent type of the transport fleet to calculate every second if there are any other agents (persons) in a range of 2meter of this transporter and if so it should slow down speed. I know a bit how to code, but since I'm used to python instead of java I found it difficult to really know how to code, so at the moment I created an event in the agent type of the AGV which runs every second (which is the agent type of the transporter).

In the code box I want something like this but do not know how to exactly:

```
for person (if person.walking=true) in personpopulation:
    if double distanceTo(person)<2:
      unit.setspeed(0.05)
        break // Since knowing that one agent is close is enough.
    unit.setspeed(2) // if there is no agent close he did not break and reaches this part of the code.
```

But how do you exactly code this in java/anylogic

Screens of current situation:
In method 1 I used the simple way by just adding the set speed function.
[image: Transporterfleet method 1]
[image: Event method 1]

Than I also tried this and in the model is see that the maxspeed parameter of the agent changes, but the movement of the AGV is not slowing down.

[image: Event method 2]
[image: Transporterfleet method2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
for (Person currPerson : personPopulation) {
    if (currPerson.walking==true) {
        for (AGV currAgv: agvPopulation) {
               if (currPerson.distanceTo(currAgv)<2){
                   currAgv.setMaximumSpeed(0.05,MPS);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: The code seems to work, but the strange thing is that the AGV is not lowering his speed when he is coming close to a person. I also tried to set the speed as an agent parameter and it indeed changes, but in the simulation my AGV seems to not slow down.

Comment: I think you need also an `else` statement inside the loop to revert to the original speed once the transporter bypasses the obstacle.

Comment: Yes that is true! But the problem is that he is not lowering speed when using the setspeed function. Somehow it seems that the transporterfleet is not changing his parameters.

Comment: Please add screenshots of what is in your `transporterFleet` block.

Comment: I added them in the original post!

Comment: Thanks and how did you define the AGV agent? Are they of type `Transporter Type`?

Comment: yes the AGV agent type is "Use in flowchart as : Transporter".

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was in the setspeed function. You have to change it to setMaximumSpeed!!

Comment: Great, happy that my answer was useful.